# Convert ITAB to XSTRING and back

Tags: string, type-conversion, abap

I need to save an itab as an xstring or something like this and save it in dbtab.
Later I need to gather this xstring from dbtab and convert it in the itab before with exactly the same input from before.

I tried a lot of fuba´s like:
`SCMS_STRING_TO_XSTRING` or `SCMS_XSTRING_TO_BINARY` but I didn´t find something to convert it back.

Does somebody have tried something like this before and have some samples for me ?

Unfortunately I didn´t find something on other blogs or else.

Comment: All these function modules do very simple ABAP stuff. Why not doing it in classic ABAP instead of calling function modules that you don't master (and which are not released for customer usage).

Comment: Thanks @SandraRossi 
I thought someone had the same problem like me and has a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy solution to convert into an xstring:

```
CALL TRANSFORMATION id SOURCE root = it_table RESULT XML DATA(lv_xstring).
```

Back would be like:

```
CALL TRANSFORMATION id SOURCE XML lv_xstring RESULT root = it_table.
```

For more information, see the ABAP documentation about data serialization and deserialization by using the [XSL Identity Transformation](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abenabap_xslt_id.htm).

Comment: Seems like a more useful solution. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
import ... from data buffer
```

and

```
export ... to data buffer
```

to (re)store any variable as xstring.

Or you can use

```
import|export ... from|to database ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but `to data buffer` isn´t the right solution for my problem, because it need to be saved for a long time. :)

Comment: You can save data buffer to DB. =)

Answer (score 0):

I did some methods to do this:

First I loop at the table and concatenate it into a string.
Then convert the string into an xstring.

```
 LOOP AT IT_TABLE ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<LS_TABLE>).
CONCATENATE LV_STRING <LS_TABLE> INTO LV_STRING SEPARATED BY CL_ABAP_CHAR_UTILITIES=>NEWLINE.
ENDLOOP.
CALL FUNCTION 'SCMS_STRING_TO_XSTRING'
    EXPORTING
      TEXT   = IV_STRING
    IMPORTING
      BUFFER = LV_XSTRING.
```

Back would be like:
Convert xstring back to string
String into table

```
 TRY.
    CL_BCS_CONVERT=>XSTRING_TO_STRING(
        EXPORTING
          IV_XSTR   = IV_XSTRING
          IV_CP     =  1100                " SAP character set identification
        RECEIVING
          RV_STRING = LV_STRING
      ).
  CATCH CX_BCS.
ENDTRY.

SPLIT IV_STRING AT CL_ABAP_CHAR_UTILITIES=>NEWLINE INTO: TABLE <LT_TABLE> .

READ TABLE <LT_TABLE> ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<LS_TABLE>) INDEX 1.
IF <LS_TABLE> IS INITIAL.
  DELETE TABLE <LT_TABLE> FROM <LS_TABLE>.
ENDIF.
```